# Ambiguous column name for left outer join code

Tags: c#, sql, forms, datagridview, inner-join

I have a datagridview on the form to display the prescription table data. I want to change my paymentID field in my prescription table to amount field which exist in payment table. But after writing the left outer join code in my select statement, when i debug, I got the error in the second image.

payment and prescription table
[image: payment and prescription]

ambiguous column name
[image: ambiguous column name]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class prescription : Form
    {

        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Prescription = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter PrescriptionAdapter;

        public prescription()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnSubmit.Text == "Clear")
            {
                btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
                ClearTextBoxes();
                txtmedicationID.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                btnSubmit.Text = "Clear";
                int result = AddPrescriptionRecord();
                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Successful");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Fail");

            }
        }

        private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            txtmedicationID.Clear();
            txtappointmentID.Clear();
        }

        private int AddPrescriptionRecord()
        {
            int result = 0;
            // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            String strCommandText = "INSERT Prescription(medicationID, appointmentID) "
                + " VALUES (@NewmedicationID, @NewappointmentID)";

            SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmedicationID", txtmedicationID.Text);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewappointmentID", txtappointmentID.Text);
            //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
            myConnect.Open();
            // STEP 4: execute command
            // indicates number of record updated.
            result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // STEP 5: Close
            myConnect.Close();
            return result;

        }

        private void prescription_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPrescriptionRecords();
        }

        private void LoadPrescriptionRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, medicationID, appointmentID, c.amount  FROM PRESCRIPTION AS a left outer join payment as c on a.paymentid = c.paymentId";

            PrescriptionAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(PrescriptionAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Prescription.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            PrescriptionAdapter.Fill(Prescription);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Prescription.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdPrescription.DataSource = Prescription;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int modifiedRows = 0;
            // Get changes
            DataTable UpdatedTable = Prescription.GetChanges();
            if (UpdatedTable != null)
            {
                // there are changes
                // Write modified data to database 
                modifiedRows = PrescriptionAdapter.Update(UpdatedTable);
                // accept changes
                Prescription.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("there are no changes to update");

            if (modifiedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + modifiedRows + " records updated");
                LoadPrescriptionRecords();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query should be like this:

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT prescriptionID, medicationID, a.appointmentID,
                         c.amount  FROM PRESCRIPTION AS a
                         left outer join payment as c
                         on a.paymentid = c.paymentId";
```

Since `appointmentID` exists in both table so you need to resolve the ambiguity by replacing `appointmentID` with `a.appointmentID`.

Answer (score 1):

Since more then one table contains `appointmentID` column you need to specify which column you want to get in your select statement

```
select ... a.appointmentID
```

or

```
select ... c.appointmentID
```

If both tables contain same `appointmentID` value then it does not matter which one you choose. Since you do *left outer join*, which suggests that *payment* entry does not have to exist, you may find that `a.appointmentID` contain some value when `c.appointmentID` would be null

Comment: You have two tables _PRESCRIPTION AS a_ and _payment as c_ and since both contain `appointmentID` column you need to specify alias of the table to get `appointmentID` from. If both table contain same `appointmentID` value then it does not matter but since you to left outer join and not inner join you may so _c_ does not have to exist you need to decide which value to take

Comment: Thanks i understand, that means if i put a.appointmentID <<this field belongs to prescription table. and if i put c.appointmentID<< this field belongs to payment table @dkozl

Comment: Yes and you need to specify which table to choose

Answer (score 0):

The name is found in both tables , Always Try to use Aliases for table names on Join Operations :

```
Select ... From Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
on t1.Key = t2.FKey
```